# iptables --list showing 172-0-0-0.lightspeed.brhmal.sbcglobal.net/8

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables

When i type sudo iptables --list i get this line appearing in my chain rules:

DROP       all  --  172-0-0-0.lightspeed.brhmal.sbcglobal.net/8  anywhere

When i type sudo iptables -n --list i get this line instead:

DROP       all  --  172.0.0.0/8          0.0.0.0/0

How come iptables tries to resolve this ip 172.0.0.0 to 172-0-0-0.lightspeed.brhmal.sbcglobal.net ?

I have tried to check 172.0.0.0 in the browser but it doesnt seem to resolve anything related..
thanks

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to handle the `127.0.0.0/8` block in your rules instead of the `172.0.0.0/8` (just two digits swap)? The former has a special meaning, the latter not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `iptables --list` does a reverse resolution of addresses and 172.0.0.0 actually resolves to 172-0-0-0.lightspeed.brhmal.sbcglobal.net:

```
vesemir:~> dig -x 172.0.0.0 +short
172-0-0-0.lightspeed.brhmal.sbcglobal.net.
```

The name also resolves back:

```
vesemir:~> dig 172-0-0-0.lightspeed.brhmal.sbcglobal.net +short
172.0.0.0
```

but it is highly unlikely there is anything there (it is network address, not a host address for any networks between /8 and /30).

`-n` option likely suppresses this resolution.

In short - nothing to worry about.